# What OS and file system for an raspberrypi NAS in apple eco-system

Tags: macos, mac, nas, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a NAS, running on a raspberry pi, which will be used entirely in an apple eco-system, and doesn't need windows support.

The NAS will be run purely from the OS SD card with no external harddrive (I don't need a lot of storage).

In this case, for the highest performance apple NAS setup on a raspberry pi setup should I be using raspbian with a NFS+ file system?

Then would I need something like SMB or AFP on top to connect it to my MAC or AppleTV?

Comment: This question is borderline incomprehensible.  Check out this [post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5165/whats-the-best-nas-for-home-usage-with-macs) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The [openmediavault](http://www.openmediavault.org) distribution is pretty good for that and easy to install and use. They have install images for Raspberry Pi.

Then share your files using SMB/CIFS.

Using a Raspberry Pi as a NAS can have downsides. They sometimes have problems running for a long time. It also isn't especially fast. In fact you might have problems streaming HD videos over the network.